# How can one filter MULTIPLE processes in Activity Monitor?

Tags: activity-monitor, monitoring

How can I look at several processes at once, instead of just one?

For example… typing in `bash`, shows `bash` processes.. how to I show both `bash` and say `httpd`?

First thoughts.. `bash|httpd`, no.  Or `bash httpd`, no.  Long story short, nothing i tried worked.  Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Command-line tools `top` and `ps` list running processes. Depending on what you're trying to do, perhaps running one of those commands and filtering the output with `grep` would be a better solution.

Comment: its just nice to keep an eye on "some processes" rather than "just one" or "all of them"....  but as is often the case, apple almost deliberately seems to disable access to any sort of usable sorting or filtering syntax - although it's all there, underneath the skin..  instead strong-arming "simplicity" - over clever, and unobtrusive implementations that would let people who need "more meta" - have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible with Activity Monitor. Unfortunately `top` doesn't accept several pids to monitor either, so you have to revert to a half-manual (and rather unelegant) solution using Terminal:

```
while :; do
    clear
    top -l 1 -pid PID-TO-MONITOR | tail -1
    top -l 1 -pid ANOTHER-PID-TO-MONITOR | tail -1
    sleep 5
done
```

Given some basic bash skills you can wrap this into a shell script if needed often.

Or open several terminal windows and run `top` on specific processes in each of them. Might be kind of heavy on your CPU though...

Comment: thanks for the answer, although the result is pretty icky...  `22057  mdworker 0.0  08:01.26 6   3   67+    267+   24M+  46M+  37M+  100M+ 2512M+ 22057 477  stuck 501 4711582+ 563+ 2541479+ 698439+ 9115613+ 4938769+ 1364892+ 35330+  18K+  95M+  localadmin` etc..  but it refreshes like a madman.. limiting the usefullness.  oh well, accepted until something dreamier comes along :-).

Answer (score 5):

Not sure when this feature was added (the original question is 8 years old at the time of this writing) BUT, this is possible now. Just hold <kbd>⇧SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>⌘COMMAND</kbd> to select multiple processes in the Activity Monitor window, and then go to the **View** menu and choose **Selected Processes**:

*in Big Sur 11.0.1 it looks like this*
[image: activity monitor selected processes]

*example, filtering only `airportd`, `authd` and `bird`*
[image: activity mon filtered]

Comment: Does this "filter" those terms and display any/all new processes that match that term? Or display only the exact set of processes that you select?

Comment: Thanks! Great hint for a great feature! Really amazing that this comes from a stock macOS utility now. Was almost sure I had to resort to 3rd party or custom shell script involving top.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @Patrix command line suggestion: use `grep` to match multiple PIDs by name. For example:

`top -s 2  -l 5 | grep -w 'bash\|httpd'`

Samples processes matching either `bash` or `httpd` every `2` seconds over `5` queries (10 seconds total to run).

More generally:

`top -s [interval time in seconds]  -l [# of intervals] | grep -w 'process1\|process2\|process3'`